# ELB amazon : 2 vpc and routing request /blog FROM A to B

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I m looking for a way to communicate (https requests) from a vpc A to another vpc B.

- VPC A is behind an Elastic load balancer (ELB) with 3 EC2
- VPC B has one server for the moment and not behind an ELB

On my ELB, when i try to add a new rule with the new target group i created ,I can't select it in the list. It's probably because it s on other VPC isn't it?

I tried by a peering connection like this:

- ASk : VPC A
- Acceptor : VPC B

I check both  dns resolutions (from A to B and B to A )
The peering connection is active.
I change my routable tables :

- I added on VPC A routage  the peering connection with the public ip
  of a server VPC B
- I added on VPC B routage  the peering connection with the public ip
  of a server(master) VPC A

No difference i can t select it on my ELB rules

What i miss ?

Could you help me please?

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Maybe this is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547533/aws-elb-multi-vpc-load-balancing

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to use a target group in one VPC, within the load balancer from another VPC.

There is functionality to allow an instance from another peered VPC (assuming that it is in the same region) however. If you create an IP based target group (in the VPC with the ALB) you can specify the IP address of the instance in the peered VPC.

More information about this is available in: [New – Application Load Balancing via IP Address to AWS & On-Premises Resources | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancing-via-ip-address-to-aws-on-premises-resources/)